# Traducción de Página Web

Tags: html, .htaccess

Me gustaria saber como puedo **traducir** mi **página web** a diferentes idiomas, en algún momento leí que se usaba el **.htaccess** pero en realidad no sé con certeza si sea de esa manera...

Por el momento tengo la **página** creada en **inglés** pero quiero que también los visitantes la puedan **traducir** al **español** con solo darle click al botón `ES`

Mi página la he creado con **HTML** puro, nada de programación

Comment: Desde el .htaccess lo único que lograrías es que se sirva una página u otra (cada una en diferentes idiomas), según, por ejemplo, la configuración preferida de idioma del cliente... Pero esto no tiene nada que ver con presionar un botón para cambiar de idioma.

Comment: Ahora bien, la pregunta parecería ser un tanto amplia como para poder abarcarla en una respuesta puntual. Quizás te sea útil leer [ask]. La idea es que investigues, intentes algo y preguntes si llegaste a un problema puntual. ¿Crees que podrías orientarla sobre algo que hayas intentado y tengas dudas específicas? Lo ideal es agregar un [mcve]. Encontrarás el enlace a **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta.